# How to remap escape insert mode to 'jk' in fish shell?

Tags: shell, vim, vi, fish

I use jk as my escape sequence in vim as well as vi-mode for bash and zshell. How do I do this in fish shell?

i.e. in vim:

```
inoremap jk <esc>
```

bash:

```
bind -m vi-insert '"jk": vi-movement-mode'
```

zsh

```
bindkey -M viins 'jk' vi-cmd-mode
```

What is the fish shell equivalent?

Comment: As I was using the oh-my-fish framework I had to add the `bind` command mentioned in the other answers to `$OMF_CONFIG/key_bindings.fish`, see [the oh-my-fish wiki](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish#dotfiles). Just mentioning in case anyone else using a framework like that is also struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a blog post that does exactly what I was looking for:

https://fedragon.github.io/blog/2015/03/22/vimode-fishshell-osx/

TLDR;)

```
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish
---------------------------------------------------
function fish_user_key_bindings
  fish_vi_key_bindings
  bind -M insert -m default jk backward-char force-repaint
end
```

And

```
~/.config/fish/config.fish
---------------------------------------------------
set fish_key_bindings fish_user_key_bindings
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful! I'm wondering if there's a way to type "jk" without triggering an escape to normal mode? E.g. in zsh if I wait longer than KEYTIMEOUT (which I have set to half a second) after typing "j", I can then continue in insert mode. It's also nice that zsh displays the "j" immediately, which I find helps with my typing flow.

Comment: Yes, you can also add "bind -M insert jj 'commandline -i j' " (without quotes)  to the function, and then typing jj will type a single j (and you can type jjk to type jk)

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you've already enabled vi mode by executing `fish_vi_key_bindings`. Otherwise the question doesn't make sense :-)

Create a file named *~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish* that contains this:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind -M insert jk "if commandline -P; commandline -f cancel; else; set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f backward-char force-repaint; end"
end
```

You can run the `bind` interactively but it won't be persistent across new fish sessions unless you create that autoloaded function. Also, if you switch between vi and emacs binding you'll want to guard that bind so it's only done for vi mode:

```
if test "$__fish_active_key_bindings" = "fish_vi_key_bindings"
    bind ....
end
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work until I put your `fish_user_key_bindings` function directly into my `config.fish`. Then it works fine.